# Eigenspace and Generalized Eigenspace on polynomial map

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the linear operator $T$ on $P(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $T:p(x) \mapsto p(x)+xp''(x)$.

I need to a) check that 1 is an eigenvalue of $T$ and compute the eigenspace $E_1$ and b) find the generalized eigenspace.

My attempt: a) Our vector space is any polynomial and our field is the reals. We need to show that $T(p(x)) = \lambda p(x)$. When $\lambda = 1$ we get that $T(p(x)) = p(x)$ which implies $p(x) + xp''(x) = p(x)$ and thus $xp''(x) = 0$. Hence $1$ is an eigenvalue for any polynomial of degree 1 or 0. And so $E_1 = \{ a + bx | a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

b) Now is where I'm really confused. The generalized eigenspace will be the set {$v ∈ V$ | $(T − λI)^mv = 0$, m > 0 }. The issue is I have no idea what $(T − I)^mv = 0)$ is supposed to mean for this map.

Any help here would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer the only question in the question :)

> The issue is I have no idea what $(T − I)^mv = 0)$ is supposed to mean for this map

$$
\because (T − I)p(x) = xp''(x)\\
\therefore (T − I)^2p(x) = x\frac{d^2}{dx^2}xp''(x)
$$

so on and so forth.